# Publish AIR app as standalone executable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

Is it possible to publish a standalone executable file with Adobe Flash Pro CS6 (AIR Desktop 3.4). Because as far as I know, it'll put an exe and the swf itself in the folder, along with META-INF and stuff like that. How could I make it into one executable file?

[image]

The .exe doesn't work standalone, it requires the .swf and the other files/folders aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files you mention are byproducts of the build. At the end of your build everything is copied into the .app folder. If you have your Air Settings set to "Application With Runtime Embedded" the .app folder will contain all dependencies to open your .exe. On OSX the .app folder is recognized as a executable package in and of itself. However there is a limitation to Windows where the .app folder only appears as a folder.

Official Flash Pro Engineer's response in this thread:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4745023

Perhaps creating a native installer would be a better solution?

Comment: Well, in CS6 it's not really working, or at least for me. Check the picture I've uploaded above.

Comment: Updated the answer with new information I found on the Adobe forums.